# Insert into HTML select tag options from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, json2html

So, here's the deal: I have a JSON object saved in my web App at localStorage.
This JSON is being saved as a string, with `JSON.stringify`, inside one of my functions, on the page load:

```
localStorage.setItem("MyData", JSON.stringify(data));
```

data is being saved like this:

`[{"NAMEVAR":"Some Data 1","CODE":"1"},{"NAMEVAR":"Some Data 2","CODE":"2"}]`

data is the result from a request. The data is being saved successfully at the home page, so i could use later. After that, i have to load up a form on another page, using what i got from data.

I have this select tag on the page:

```
<select id="mySelectID" name="select" class="main-form">
<option value="">None Selected</option>
</select>
```

What i want to do is simple: I'm using [json2html](http://www.json2html.com/) to add items to this select tag from the data, and the option value has the CODE from data.
So, what i expected to happen is:

```
<select id="mySelectID" name="select" class="main-form">
<option value="1">Some Data 1</option>
<option value="2">Some Data 2</option>
</select>
```

by doing this:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
var transform = {tag:'option', id:'.CODE',html:'{$NAMEVAR}'};
document.getElementById('mySelectID').innerHtml = json2html.transform(jsonData,transform);
```

But this does not work, and i know it won't. The problem is that i do not know how to insert this JSON into options to my HTML. I thought that json2html could help me, but as i do not speak English natively, it's kinda of being hard for me to understand that, and I'm also new to JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the transform for this, try it this way:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));

var $select = $('#mySelectID');
$(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.CODE).text(o.NAMEVAR);
    $select.append($option);
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87xpB/).

Answer (score 8):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'test.html',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'q=' + str,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
           $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Please always explain how your solution works and why it is a good idea for the benefit of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of errors in your code. Try this instead:

```
// it's class, not id, and no fullstop required.
// The $ sign was in the wrong place.
var transform = {tag:'option', class:'$(CODE)', html:'${NAMEVAR}'};

// it's innerHTML not innerHtml
document.getElementById('mySelectID').innerHTML = json2html.transform(jsonData, transform);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are starting you can learn more of JavaScript from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/). There is an DOM object called [Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) that you can use to add an option into select. You just need to do something like:

```
var el = document.getElementById('mySelectID'); //Get the select element
var opt = document.createElement('option'); //Create option element
opt.innerHTML = "it works!"; //Add a value to the option

el.appendChild(opt); //Add the option to the select element
```

Answer (score 1):

to answer the actual question on how to do this in json2html .. with the correct transform

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
var transform = {tag:'option', id:'${CODE}',html:'${NAMEVAR}'};
document.getElementById('mySelectID').innerHtml = json2html.transform(jsonData,transform);
```

OR using the [jquery plugin](https://github.com/moappi/jquery.json2html) for json2html

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
var transform = {tag:'option', id:'${CODE}',html:'${NAMEVAR}'};
$('#mySelectID').json2html(jsonData,transform);
```

Answer (score -1):

most immediately you need to change this:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
var transform = {tag:'option', id:'.CODE',html:'{$NAMEVAR}'};
```

To this:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("MyData"));
var transform = {tag:'option', id:'{$CODE}',html:'{$NAMEVAR}'};
```

That's just a key to get to the data, so make sure you use the same key.

There may be some difficulty in rendering:

```
value="1"
```

As you are depending id="{$CODE}" to translate to that, which it will not do automatically.

Good luck!

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why he downvoted this? :O