# Jquery autocomplete from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete

Please solve this issue:
I have the json format array in external js: (NOT Ajax(json) request)

```
var data = [{"Id": 0,"City": "Chicago"},{"Id": 1,"City": "New York"},...]
```

I need to create Jquery autocomplete form **with arrow**. Maybe it will be: 
select
Chicago (from external JS) 
New York
/select, 
or textarea, input. One thing is **required**: **arrow will be visible**, because user may choose elements with mouse.
How to attach array to html page?

**Image**

[image]

Comment: So you're asking how to get JSON data into an HTML `<select>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JSON data to populate the options of a select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918144/how-can-i-use-json-data-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-box)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442422/jquery-populate-select-from-json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496203/insert-into-html-select-tag-options-from-a-json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637694/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-with-json-data-in-jquery

Comment: I need to get json data array in external JS into HTML <select> or <textarea> or <input>. But arrow will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here it shows all the items containing the word in input. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u0cejce/#&togetherjs=c3GnLMPMHV). May it helps.

```js
var data = [{"Id": 0,"City": "Chicago"},
           {"Id": 1,"City": "New York"},
           {"Id": 2,"City": "Aew York1"},
           {"Id": 3,"City": "Bew York2"}]
           
$.each(data,function(i,item){
 var $option=$('<option>',{val:item.Id,text:item.City});
 $('#tags').append($option);
})

$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" ).appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )

          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

 

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false

          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is( ":visible" );
          })

          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger("focus");
            // Close if already visible

            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );

          });

      },

 

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );

        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      }, 

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;

        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
        // Found a match, nothing to do

        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value

        this.input.val( "" ).attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" ).tooltip("open");
        this.element.val( "" );

        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });



    $( "#tags" ).combobox();
```

```css
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<div>
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <select id="tags"></select>
</div>
```